# Gregorian Chant - Is it merely a form of music, like Hymns, or is there a deeper meaning?

Tags: catholicism, music

The title says it all.  Is Gregorian Chant merely a style of music, or is there some deeper meaning behind it?  Does it serve some special purpose, or have a usage beyond being a form of worshiping God through song?

Comment: I just updated my quesiton to be more clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During the St. Gregory I papacy (590–604) this form of music was collected and codified, and was (and still is) strictly linked to the liturgy.

In this sense, this is not just a style of music, but it goes together with the Mass and the prayer of "The canonical hours", consisting of eight prayer services: Matins, Lauds, Prime, Terce, Sext, None, Vespers, and Compline.

Gregorian Chant purpose was hence to accompaign the liturgy, but the liturgy itself was build together with the chant. In this sense it has a deeper meaning. It's part of the liturgy.

There are the following good links you could view, which give more detail about the chant.

- [Gregorian Chant @Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/245481/Gregorian-chant)
- [Gregorian Chant @catholic encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/06779a.htm)

In general, Gregorian Chant is part of the longlasting Church tradition. It is now still commonly used by Order of Saint Benedict and other monastic orders. In this sense you can find a deeper meaning, because it recalls all the monastic tradition ellements: the silence, the prayer of the hearth.. and others.

I hope this answers to your question.